# Laravel eloquent and a simple database query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel 9. PHP 8.0.

The task is to write an array line by line. Can you tell me why writing with eloquent in this form does not work, while writing as DB select works fine. What is my problem?

Original code

```
$task = $request['task'];
$datetask = $request['datetask'];
$timetask = $request['timetask'];
        
for ($i = 0; $i < count($task ); $i++) {
    DB::insert('insert into tasks (task,datetask,timetask,)values(?,?,?)',
                [$task[$i],$datetask[$i],$timetask[$i]]);
};
```

and Eloquent code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($task); $i++) {
    $task= new Task;
    $task->task = $request['task'];
    $task->datetask = $request['datetask'];
    $task->timetask = $request['timetask'];
    $task->save();
}
```

Error:

> Array to string conversion.

Line::  `$task->save();`

Comment: Please tell us the _exact_ error message, and the line it occurs on. Paraphrased, abbreviated, or otherwise altered error message descriptions are generally of no real use to anyone. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. `count($task)` appears to make no sense when you are defining `$task` as a `Task` object within the loop. Was `$task` defined _before_ the loop started? If so, don't re-use a variable name for something else! It is guaranteed to cause confusion, and very likely to cause actual bugs too.

Comment: Error Array to string conversion. Line ```  $task->save();```

Comment: Please [edit] your queestion with the full error message and line details. Important info like this does not belong, unformatted and hidden away, in the comments :-)

Comment: Yes, the variable for the loop was predefined. But its name probably causes an error. I'm trying it in the real one with a different name

Comment: That is a problem, but also the issue is likely caused by what RohanKumar pointed out in the answer below - you forgot that your $request variable contains arrays, even though you had taken it into account in the original code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting array to string conversion so you need to use loop with `[i]` for all 3 param values

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request['task']); $i++) {
  $objTask= new Task; // don't use $task, which is already defined
  $objTask->task = $request['task'][$i]; // missing [$i] here
  $objTask->datetask = $request['datetask'][$i];
  $objTask->timetask = $request['timetask'][$i];
  $objTask->save();
}
```

Or if you are passing array values directly, then don't use loop

```
  // for ($i = 0; $i < count($request['task']); $i++) {
  $objTask= new Task; // don't use $task, which is already defined
  $objTask->task = $request['task']; // passing request param directly
  $objTask->datetask = $request['datetask'];
  $objTask->timetask = $request['timetask'];
  $objTask->save();
  // }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Eloquent, you have missed to use the loop variable `$i`.
In your original code you are passing variables with `[$i]` as

```
DB::insert('insert into tasks (task,datetask,timetask,)values(?,?,?)',
                [$task[$i],$datetask[$i],$timetask[$i]]);
```

You need to use same variable

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($task); $i++) {
    $task= new Task;
    $task->task = $task[$i];
    $task->datetask = $datetask[$i];
    $task->timetask =$timetask[$i]];
    $task->save();
}
```

Or just use **[$i]** with your data.

```
 $objTask->task = $request['task'][$i];
 $objTask->datetask = $request['datetask'][$i];
 $objTask->timetask = $request['timetask'][$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert multiple records without loop, try this.

```
//considering $task is muti record array.
Task::insert($task);
```